# method mocking and sqlalchemy (psycopg2)

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, mocking, psycopg2

I have the method, which does some job, returns some value and passes it to sqlalchemy query.
In case of test, I try to mock this method, but got exception: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'MagicMock'`

I have code, which looks like this:

```
from mock import patch
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column

from pr.core.model import Base
from pr.core.model import Session


class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class SomeObj(object):
    def some_method(self):
        return 1

    def call(self):
        return Session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.id == self.some_method()).all()


def main():
    with patch('__main__.SomeObj.some_method') as mocked:
        SomeObj().call()
        assert mocked.called
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After calling such code, I got such traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/core/run/stuff.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/core/run/stuff.py", line 23, in main
    SomeObj().call()
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/core/run/stuff.py", line 18, in call
    return Session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.id == self.some_method()).all()
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2613, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/core/model/cachingquery.py", line 74, in __iter__
    return Query.__iter__(self)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2761, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2776, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/anton/Projects/pr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'MagicMock' [SQL: 'SELECT "table".id AS table_id \nFROM "table" \nWHERE "table".id = %(id_1)s'] [parameters: {'id_1': <MagicMock name='some_method()' id='140314377476560'>}]
```

Is there any way to mock method properly?

Comment: You're trying to pass the default return value of the mocked method to SQL, or in other words an instance of `MagickMock`. Set `mocked.return_value` to something appropriate before the call.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I want to avoid it. In case of test, I just want to check if method called.

Comment: You cannot avoid it in your current method, unless you mock the whole of SQLAlchemy. You are calling a function to produce a value that will be used in an SQL expression. A `MagickMock` instance is a poor choice of value, as you've seen. All in all your `call()` method is a bit odd. You select values from your DB, but don't return them. Is this your real code, or a very simplified example?

Comment: @IljaEverilä just minimum example, of course. If you return something, actually nothing changes. But ok, I edited the example :)

Comment: The thing is: you're really hitting the DB, so you cannot pass garbage to the comparison SQL expression. You'd have to abstract the DB away as well, if you just want to see if certain functions are called.